# Unexpected output with left shift operator C++

Tags: c++

Here is the code which is giving me the unexpected answer

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<(1<<50);
}
```

The answer I get is 0.
But if I change the line to

```
cout<<pow(2, 50);
```

I get the right answer.

Could someone explain me the reason.

Comment: integer overflow is my guess. (`main.cpp:5:20: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]` compiler warnings are your friends, listen to them)

Comment: How many bits are in `1`?

Comment: does <<16 work?  Guessing you've gone off the left hand edge

Comment: by the way, do **not** use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` - it's not standard compliant

Comment: consider `pow` returns a `double`, which may actually be able to represent 2^50, while `1<<50` is an `int`, which can't

Comment: try `1ULL << 50`

Comment: @StoryTeller sometimes I am not sure about something and just post it even if there are high chances that it is wrong. Once again I learned something. Thx, I better remove the comment, not because of my shame, but not to confuse others that are as ignorant as me ;)

Comment: @M.M I tried it worked. Is it 64 bit unsigned?

Comment: @VarunSaproo - It's the largest fundamental integral data type. On modern systems it's most likely 64 bit. Don't assume it *has* to be 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shift the "1" out of the 32 bit field, so zero is the result. Pow uses float representation where 2^50 can be handled.

***EDIT***

Without any modifications like "1LL" or "1ULL" (which generate long 64bit numbers), an integer number is usually handled as 32 bit on a x64 or x86 architectures. You can use

```
 cout << (1ULL << 50);
```

or

```
 cout << ((long long)1 << 50);
```

which should to it.

Comment: What 32bit field?

Comment: Note that `int` may or may not be 32bit large.

Comment: 1 is handled as a signed integer number which has 32 bit on a common PC.

Comment: @ThomasJahn What if I don't use a common PC? You should definitely mention that.

Comment: The size of a signed integer number is chosen by the compiler (which will most likely choose one that is well suited for the target architecture, but that's not required), the standard only states that `int` has to be at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: "cout << (static_cast<int64_t>(1) << 50) << endl;"  also works, and fully documents the size of integer you intended.  (static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 50) too

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your compiler treats the constant `1` as a 32bit integer, you shifted it so far to the left, that only zeroes remain in the 32bit you have. 50 is larger than 32.

Comment: So is there any way I could shift to 50?

Comment: Try `1ULL << 50`.

Comment: @VarunSaproo Sure, just put your constant into a 64bit variable. For example `int64_t` from `#include <stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ Standard (5.8 Shift operators)

> 1 The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.

```
shift-expression:
    additive-expression
    shift-expression << additive-expression
    shift-expression >> additive-expression
```

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
>   integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of
>   the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right
>   operand is** negative, or **greater than or equal to the length in
>   bits of the promoted left operand**.

Take into account that the behavior also will be undefined if the right operand is not greater or equal to the length in bits of the left operand but can touch the sign bit because the integer literal `1` has the type `signed int`.

As for this function call `pow(2, 50)` then there is used some algorithm that calculates the power.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ([run it](http://ideone.com/r09gL0)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::int64_t i { 1 }; // wide enough to allow 50 bits shift
  std::cout << std::hex << ( i << 50 );  // should display 4000000000000
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what you're doing. You're shifting a single bit by 50 position in a portion of memory that's 32 bit... What's happening according to you? The bit goes somewhere else but it's not inside the memory portion of the integer anymore. `pow(2, 50)` performs a `double` casting, so you're not shifting bits anymore.

Also, never use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. [It's not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), and it's slow. You should use it only in precompiled headers but I'd avoid this also in that cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<(1<<50);
```

Your code treats `1` as an `int`, so overflows. Instead, try:

```
cout << (1ULL << 50);
```